# Unity - Vector3 ERROR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Where is the problem? : In weapon code.
>
> Error : Vector3
>
> Which Game Engine? : Unity

I'm making an Online FPS game. This is my weapon code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class silah : MonoBehaviour {

public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;

public Camera fpscam;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpscam.transform.rotation, fpscam.transform.forward out hit, range)) 
            {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But in this part it gives me Vector3 error:

```
RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpscam.transform.rotation, fpscam.transform.forward out hit, range)) 
        {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }
```

Where I did wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it gives me Vector3 error". What *exactly* is the error message? Is it a compile-time error, or an exception? Please copy and paste the error into your question.

Comment: Note that `fpscam.transform.forward out hit` looks suspicious. Did you mean `fpscam.transform.forward, out hit` perhaps? (Note the comma.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the `Shoot` function **inside** `Update` and you missed a coma as indicated by @DaisyShipton

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}
void Shoot()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpscam.transform.position, fpscam.transform.forward, out hit, range)) 
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
    }
}
```

Edit: @Alexey pointed out the problem of the first parameter of the `Physics.Raycast`

Answer (score 0):

`fpscam.transform.rotation` returns `Quaternion`. `Physics.Raycast` method takes as the first parameter `Vector3`. Try changing first parameter to `fpscam.transform.position`

Watch https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html